# Why does Windows open CSV in Notepad and not Excel?

Tags: java, windows, file, web-applications, file-association

Our ERP uses a Java client application that connects to the database.

The application lets you run a report and open a .csv file

However, for some people, running the report will download a file open in Microsoft Excel as expected.

For some other people, running the report opens Notepad and displays a message like this:

```
---------------------------
Notepad
---------------------------
'https:\\mycompany.domain.com\folder\report\customerreport_accom.csv?encodeduserpidm=VllIU1NKVVBUTFdUS05SNg==&term=2019AA&listtype=ALL&encodedstudid=' was not found.
Do you want to create a new document?
---------------------------
Yes   No   Cancel   
---------------------------
```

Clicking "yes", throws an error like this :

```
---------------------------
Notepad
---------------------------
File operation failed.

https:\\mycompany.domain.com\folder\report\customerreport_accom.csv?encodeduserpidm=VllIU1NKVVBUTFdUS05SNg==&term=2019AA&listtype=ALL&encodedstudid=

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have checked the Windows file associations on the machines that throw errors, and they seem correct.

[image: file associations look good]

.csv files are set to always open in Excel.  If I save a .csv on the desktop and double-click, it opens correctly in Excel ( not Notepad )

We suspect that the problem is related to the users Windows profile, because two people have logged into the same computer - one sees the error, one does not.

Also, when the person who sees the error logs into the java application and runs the report, it works correctly, so it's not the user account in the java application.

Can someone tell me why the URL like the one below would open in Notepad ?  Windows does not recognize this as a .csv :

> https:\mycompany.domain.com\folder\report\customerreport_accom.csv?encodeduserpidm=VllIU1NKVVBUTFdUS05SNg==&term=2019AA&listtype=ALL&encodedstudid=

Interestingly, if I copy/paste the URL into a browser, it always works, regardless of the computer or user.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, as it comes down to who application the user has associated with the CSV file format.  If you want to force them to open it in Excel, you should save as an XLSX format instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, because it's a Java application that creates the report, the company believes that developers need to solve it.  The file associations are set up correctly in Windows, but Excel isn't launching the report from a URL correctly for some users.  If there is a better StackOverflow site to ask about file associations you can suggest, I will look there.

Comment: In that case, my suggestion is to save it as an XLSX and not a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem on the Windows profiles that were having errors.

In the file associations, .htm was associated to Notepad

Even though the URL looks like it should be a .csv, the headers are actually web page headers :

> https:\mycompany.domain.com\folder\report\customerreport_accom.csv?encodeduserpidm=VllIU1NKVVBUTFdUS05SNg==&term=2019AA&listtype=ALL&encodedstudid=

Once it opens in a browser, users are given a prompt to either download the file, or open in Excel